# Before And After In Local.xml Magento?

Tags: magento-1.4, magento-1.5, magento

I've managed to get to the point where I understand how to move blocks from column to column in my Magento layouts: via specifying a "left" or "right" attribute in the `<reference>` tag. However, I don't understand how to change the *order* in which blocks appear. I've noticed that the "before" and "after" attributes of the `<block>` tag have something to do it with, but I'm not sure how they work. If I want to move a block from the top of its area to anywhere else in our page, what's the proper use and syntax for those attributes?

For example, I have a Category page and I have these blocks in it:

- `view.phtml`
- - `list.phtml`
- - - `toolbar.phtml`

... and so on.

I want to put my block anywhere within these blocks, or at the top of these blocks, or make all of these blocks show up inside another block. How can I use "before" and "after" to achieve this using my `local.xml` file?

Note: I can do it manually by inheriting their respective .xml files, but that's not a good solution to the problem as a whole.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`before`: Used to position the block before a block with the name specified in the value. If "-" value used the block is positioned before all other blocks of its level of block nesting.

`after`: Used to position the block after a block with the name specified in the value. If "-" value used the block is positioned after all other blocks of its level of block nesting.

Updated: examples from some random core layout updates:

```
<reference name="right">
    <block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" before="cart_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
</reference>

<reference name="right">
    <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" before="-" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

**Updated:** I believe `before` and `after` work only in `core/text_list` and similar(descendant) blocks, i.e. blocks which just render blocks their nested blocks.

Comment: what is before="cart_sidebar" ? Is it template name, block name or anything else .?

Comment: @Showket `before`: **Used to position the block before a block with the name specified in the value.** What is not clear here?

Comment: I am Not understanding If I am writing before = "Some Block Name" Eg In Above Example if i want the above second block Before the First one Do I need to Write it Something Like This                .
<reference name="right">
    <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" before="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
</reference>

Comment: Thanks For giving ur precious Time...Zyava

Comment: Blocks order is as they declared within parent block/handle. If you wish to change blocks order in your theme/module without editing core layout updates - you should use after/before attributes. Make sense?

Comment: And I'm almost sure that after and before only works inside blocks of type *_list. I.e: core/text_list type blocks, like "right", "top.menu" blocks. I didn't make it work with blocks like "footer" (after="footer or after="-" using footer as reference).

Comment: Actually, it depends on how children blocks are rendered in parent block template file.

Comment: @RicardoMartins your note saved me from reading all the core code to know what's wrong with my XML layout, however I hardly noticed this tiny comment. Such useful info should be added as an answer even if not chosen, but would be better indexed.

Comment: `Updated: examples from some random core layout updates:`, you Didn't explain anything using those examples. Please edit and let us all know how the example uses after and before. Thanks anyways.