# Magento: Cart, Payment method ordering

Tags: php, magento

I'm running 1.9.x and have 3 different payment methods, amazon payments, paypal express, sage pay and a continue shopping button. On the cart page I am attempting to reorder how these appear in the checkout-types UL.

I currently have the below which I believe is default

```
<ul class="checkout-types">
        <li><?php if($this->getContinueShoppingUrl()): ?>
                                <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Continue Shopping') ?>" class="button btn-continue btn-inline" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getContinueShoppingUrl() ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue Shopping') ?></span></span></button>
                            <?php endif; ?></li>
        <?php foreach ($this->getMethods('top_methods') as $method): ?>
            <?php if ($methodHtml = $this->getMethodHtml($method)): ?>
             <li><?php echo $methodHtml; ?></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
```

My aim is to have the pay now button which goes into the one page checkout button appear after the continue shopping button and then amazon and paypal. I have spent hours looking through the code and can't seem to find a way to change the sort order on the $method array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding the following to the checkout layout sorted the issue

```
before="checkout.cart.methods.amazonpayments_pay.top"
```

Answer (score 1):

The `getMethods($name)` method will actually fall for sorting to the configuration in the layout files.

As an example for `top_methods` which is an alias in the layout, it will look for all the updates on that handle from XML files in the system, in case of PayPal it will be, *Considering that RWD is the package you are using* :
`app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/paypal.xml`

And this is the xml block part for it:

```
    <block type="paypal/express_shortcut" name="checkout.cart.methods.paypal_express.top" before="checkout.cart.methods.onepage.top" template="paypal/express/shortcut.phtml">
        <action method="setIsQuoteAllowed"><value>1</value></action>
        <action method="setShowOrPosition"><value>after</value></action>
    </block>
```

In this default theme configuration, the paypal express checkout is placed before the block `checkout.cart.methods.onepage.top` which is configured to be the last block in `top_methods` with the `after="-"` :

```
    <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.top_methods" as="top_methods" translate="label">
            <label>Payment Methods Before Checkout Button</label>
            <block type="checkout/onepage_link" name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage.top" template="checkout/onepage/link.phtml" after="-" />
    </block>
```

So in conclusion, what you need to do is to go through the XML layout files for the payment methods you are using, and [set the `before` and `after` depending on the sort you need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093603/before-and-after-in-local-xml-magento). if you have cache enabled, you will need to flush it and you should get the result intended.

An example would be:

[Change display order of checkout buttons in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032267/change-display-order-of-checkout-buttons-in-magento)